# Form1 [Design] loads a blank template after renaming an event handler

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013

In VS2013, I renamed one of my button event handlers and wanted to drop into the [Design] to change the property. I got a huge warning telling me that things are not as they seem (expected, since I changed the delegate's name) so I hit Ignore and Continue. This is the first time I've hit this button.

To my horror, what I saw was ... a blank template as opposed to my original winform. I have backups of my code, so I'm not too worried, but I was wondering how I'd go about restoring my Form1.cs[Design] without going back a code rev.

This is what my [Design] looks like now:

[image]

Comment: You mean you changed the name in Form1.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Did your error say this?:

[image]

By renaming the delegate in your code file, you hung the designer out to dry. Everytime you switch to the designer tab, it parses InitializeComponent() to draw your controls for editing, and since the reference to the original callback doesn't exist anymore, the designer doesn't know what to do when it encounters the unknown reference. By forcing its hand, it simply craps out like it was telling you it was going to do. The blank panel is just a result of it failing and drawing nothing.

Pop open your Form1.Designer file and find where the button's properties are set. The unknown reference is probably highlighted in red. Change the name to whatever you changed in your other file. Here's an example, but with a panel instead of a button:

[image]

And then your designer should return to normal. No worries about rolling anything back, it's a minor fix.

Comment: Will check on this; I rolled back quickly for a small project presentation and will come back to this. Thanks!